# Unable to apply display:flex to body element of iframe on Safari?

Tags: css

I have been trying to apply a rule to body element of an iframe like so:

```
body {
  background:white; 
  margin:0; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  height:100vh; 
  width:100vw; 
  font-size: 3vw; 
  display:flex !important; 
  align-items:center; 
  justify-content:center; }
```

But what it instead applies on Safari is this:

```
  body{
    display:block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px; ...}
```

It overrides the rules I set for both margin and display with its own defaults *UserAgent stylesheet. Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

[Update] As of iOS7+ updates this bug is no longer valid.

Comment: Style rules don't cascade between parent document and iFrame documents.

Comment: That's not in the parent. It's inside the iframe. The question is pre-iOS 7, when the support wasn't there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set class to body like that

```
    .anyClass{
       display:flex;
       ...
    }
```

If this will not work try to send jsFidle code

Comment: or try to define display by specific marks like 
  'display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;'

Comment: That wouldn't work. If you see the rules in my question above, `display:flex` is already written there.